# How to reduce selected comment distance from code in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

When I use IntelliJ idea and comment some portion of code, the comments are always close to code like below

[image: intellij idea short comment]

But in Android Studio comments are far away from the code like below

[image: android studio long comment]

How can I achieve comment settings like Intellij Idea in Android Studio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it you are trying to comment the codes by selecting them all and using the comment option right. To achieve what you are looking for:

In Android Studio, go to File-->Settings-->Editor-->Code Style-->Java ...You can select the language you want, java as an example.. On the right You then have to select the 'Code Generation' tab, below a checkbox will show Line comment at first column untick that and your comments will be shown right next to the first indented line in your selection.

[image]

Comments generated will all be in one column based on the first line closest to the first column in your selection.
Check if this works for you.

On another you can always use block comment to easily comment a whole block `/*....*/` or finally you can click anywhere you want and type `//` manually where you want it to be, a bit too tedious though. but works.

Comment: Good! in which case if there are no other issues you may accept this as an answer to let others know your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

Android Studio > File > Setting > Editor > trailing in this uncheck the Always keep trailing spaces on caret line also use ctrl+alt+l to reformat the code.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find the option

Comment: you can search in search bar given in settings